# Hibernate Cannot locate named parameter exception

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

My exception message is:

```
org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named parameter [searchKey] at
org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.ParameterMetadata.getNamedParameterDescriptor(ParameterMetadata.java:148) at 
org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.ParameterMetadata.getNamedParameterExpectedType(ParameterMetadata.java:165) at
org.hibernate.internal.AbstractQueryImpl.determineType(AbstractQueryImpl.java:523) at
org.hibernate.internal.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameter(AbstractQueryImpl.java:493) at
com.si.bse.dao.impl.SearchDaoImpl.getClientList(SearchDaoImpl.java:99) at 
com.si.bse.services.impl.SearchServicesImpl.getClientList(SearchServicesImpl.java:32)
```

and the code that is throwing it is:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Transactional
@Override
public List<Client> getClientList(String searchWord) {
    String sql = "select * from client c join clientcategory cc on c.id=cc.client_id where match(cc.clientkeyword) against(':searchKey' in boolean mode)";

    SQLQuery query = (SQLQuery) getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(sql).addEntity(Client.class).setParameter("searchKey", searchWord);

    List result = query.list();
    return result;
}
```

Why can Hibernate not find my named parameter?

Comment: try query with `select * from client c join clientcategory cc on c.id=cc.client_id where match(cc.clientkeyword) against(:searchKey in boolean mode)`

Comment: you can specify the parameter type in `setParameter`. have a look https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#setParameter%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object,%20org.hibernate.type.Type%29

Comment: I have tidied your code and exception block. Make sure that you have thoroughly researched this exception. It should be a fairly easy fix.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to put single quote `'` for parameter place holder `':searchKey'`. removing that quotes may solve your problem.

So the query will be :

`select * from client c join clientcategory cc on c.id=cc.client_id where match(cc.clientkeyword) against(:searchKey in boolean mode)`

You can specify Datatype of parameter using overloaded setParameter(), which accepts 3 parameters

1. the name of the parameter
2. parameter value
3. the Hibernate type

For more info about method Plz refer [Hibernate doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#setParameter%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object,%20org.hibernate.type.Type%29).